# Output fault with array in C

Tags: c

This code is working but no output whats is the my fault? I, want take array and I want to write this array and compare this array's columns and rows. But this code don't have output. And another problem is i want to use dynamic programming how can I do it?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double CompFunc(int *n, int *m, int *x, int *y) {

  int first[*n][*m];
  srand(time(0));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      first[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
  }

  printf("First array:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      printf("%d", first[i][j]);
      if (j == m - 1) {
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }

  int second[*x][*y];
  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      second[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
  }

  printf("Second array:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      printf("%d ", second[i][j]);
      if (j == y - 1) {
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }

  if (n == x || m == y)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main() {
  int a, b, c, d;
  printf("How many elements do you want in the first array's column:");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("How many elements do you want in the first array's row:");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  printf("How many elements do you want in the second array's column:");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("How many elements do you want in the second array's row:");
  scanf("%d", &d);
  CompFunc(&a, &b, &c, &d);
}
```

Comment: what compiler are you using? using gcc 7.5.0 I couldn't even get your original code to compile because of the comparison mismatches between pointers and numbers

Comment: as another piece of advice, using variable length arrays isn't advised.

```
  int second[*x][*y];
```

it's a little more difficult, but the recommendation is to use malloc for variably-sized arrays. The problem is that if you try and make an array that's too big it could crash your program (e.g. you'd encounter an error known as stack overflow)

Comment: i using dev c++ 5.11

Answer (score 1):

one thing I'm noticing is that the variables `n`, `m`, `x`, and `y` are all declared as pointers, `int*` but when you are iterating over them in your for loops you are not dereferencing them.

e.g.

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ // you wrote

    for(int i=0; i<*n; i++){ // but you should dereference n
```

Comment: Scott, thx for your answer output is come but wrong output and arrays not shows like matrix  shows like=12345678987 how can i change this?

Comment: hi @can to provide help people on stack overflow need you to provide more information. how is the output wrong? what is it showing and what would you expect?

Comment: sorry I'm not clear what left and right you are referring to.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you are just forgetting to print out a space when you are printing out the first matrix

you wrote      printf("%d", first[i][j]);

should be      printf("%d ", first[i][j]);